# Dell iDRAC6 virtual console viewer from GNU/Linux command line

Tags: console, drac

I am annoyed that I have to launch a webbrowser just because I want to use the virtual console through the iDRAC6.

I managed to download `viewer.jnlp` and I can start the viewer with:

```
javaws viewer.jnlp
```

But it seems `viewer.jnlp` changes for each run. Specifically:

```
<argument>user=1234567890</argument>                                                   
<argument>passwd=123456789</argument>
```

My guess is that iDRAC6 makes a random user/password for each run and that this can be used only once.

I would much prefer, if I could simply do:

```
drac-virtual-console-viewer username password drac.ip.nr
```

Is there a tool for that?

Or is there a way I can download the `viewer.jnlp` given the username/password?

It seems other versions of the iDRAC support VNC, but I cannot get that to work on the iDRAC6. But if I could get that to work, it would also solve my problem.

System: Dell R815 iDRAC6

Comment: Have you heard or used racadm? It's a command-line tool you use to tweak iDRAC, BIOS, get logs, etc. You don't see the BIOS startup in a GUI, but you can query BIOS settings & set those settings. I think its available for iDRAC6 & Linux? https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/04/integrated-dell-remote-access-cntrllr-8-with-lifecycle-controller-v2.00.00.00/racadm_idrac_pub-v1/racadm-command-options?guid=guid-a8d2b6ad-f890-4a5c-a3bd-09e9f8891d0e&lang=en-us

Answer (score 11, accepted):

assuming iDRAC IP is 10.64.31.76

download this file `https://10.64.31.76:443/software/avctKVM.jar` from your idrac

run:

```
java -cp Downloads/avctKVM.jar com.avocent.idrac.kvm.Main ip=10.64.31.76 kmport=5900 vport=5900 user=root passwd=calvin apcp=1 version=2 vmprivilege=true "helpurl=https://10.64.31.76:443/help/contents.html"
```

user and root passwords are the idrac credentials.

I got a working console

tested with:

- Windows 10
- java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)
- iDRAC 6 Enterprise
- PowerEdge R310

credits to: https://gist.github.com/xbb/4fd651c2493ad9284dbcb827dc8886d6

Comment: Now there is also a GNU/Linux command: https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/-/tree/master/drac

Comment: @Ole: Tops for the solution. Mixing `foo` and $(bar) in one script, please don't :).

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 console available:

1. VGA via iDRAC VNC
2. Serial via IPMI Serial Over Lan

**VGA**

1. Install JDK
2. Linux workstation: download `avctVMLinux64.jar` and `avctKVMIOLinux64.jar`. Create a `lib` folder, then unpack `libavctKVMIO.so` and `libavmlinux.so` into `lib/` folder. You can find the URLs in the `*.jnlp` file.
3. Windows workstation: download similar files found in `*.jnlp`. Download `avctVMWin64.jar` and `avctKVMIOWin64.jar`. Create `lib` folder, then unpack `avctKVMIO.dll` and `avmlinux.dll` into `lib` folder.
4. Edit `jre/lib/security/java.security` and make sure you remove `3DES_EDE_CBC` from `jdk.tls.legacyAlgorithms=`
5. Import SSL certificate: `$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -importcert -file <(echo ""|openssl s_client -connect iDRACHostName:443 2>/dev/null|openssl x509) -alias iDRACHostName -noprompt`
6. Connect: `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java  -cp avctKVM.jar -Djava.library.path=./lib com.avocent.idrac.kvm.Main ip=iDRACHostName kmport=5900 vport=5900 apcp=1 version=2 vmprivilege=true helpurl=https://iDRACHostName:443/help/contents.html user=Administrator passwd=ipmi_password`

**IPMI SOL**

1. Configure serial redirection in BIOS
2. Linux: configure serial support in GRUB and install and configure a serial `agetty`
3. Windows: enable serial console, then reboot: `bcdedit /ems {current} on` then `bcdedit /emssettings EMSPORT:1 EMSBAUDRATE:115200`
4. Connect: `ipmitool -I lanplus -H iDRACHostName -U Administrator -P password sol activate`

Comment: How does your first solution differ from exeral's? It seems the last command is essentially the same.

Comment: This improves on the accepted answer. The added details around the security exceptions and importing the certificate made this work for me, whereas the simple version did not.

Answer (score 2):

This is by far the easiest way: https://github.com/DomiStyle/docker-idrac6

A web based docker container that gives you full functionality!